# Why redux state is not render correctly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, async-await

Good day, I faced an issue when tried to push the user to the dashboard after the user login correctly but it didn't, here is the code below:

> LoginForm.js

```
const { isLoading, isAuth, error, message } = useSelector(
(state) => state.login
);
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
console.log(values);//values={email:'..', pass:'..'}
if (formValidation()) {
  dispatch(NewUserLogin(values)); 
  console.log(isAuth); //print false but in redux state print true
  if (isAuth) history.push('/dashboard');
 }
};
```

> LoginAction.js

```
export const NewUserLogin = (formValues) => async (dispatch) => {
try {
 dispatch(loginPending());
 const { status, message } = await LoginAPIRequest(formValues);

 if (status === 'success') {
  dispatch(loginSuccess(message));
 } else {
  dispatch(loginFailure(message));
 }
 console.log(status);
 console.log(message);
} catch (error) {
  dispatch(loginFailure(error.message));
 }
};
```

> loginSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
const initialState = {
isLoading: false,
isAuth: false,
error: '',
};
const loginSlice = createSlice({
 name: 'Login',
 initialState,
 reducers: {
  loginPending: (state) => {
  state.isLoading = true;
  },
  loginSuccess: (state, { payload }) => {
   state.isLoading = false;
   state.isAuth = true;
   state.message = payload;
   state.error = '';
  },
  loginFailure: (state, { payload }) => {
  //actions.payload or shortcut {payload}
   state.isLoading = false;
   state.error = payload;
  },
 },
});

const { reducer, actions } = loginSlice;
export const { loginPending, loginSuccess, loginFailure } = actions;
export default reducer;
```

> userAPI.js

```
import { createEndpointsAPI, ENDPOINTS } from './index';

export const LoginAPIRequest = (formValues) => {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  //call api
  try {
    await createEndpointsAPI(ENDPOINTS.LOGIN)
      .create(formValues)
      .then((res) => {
        resolve(res.data);
        if (res.data.status === 'success') {
          resolve(res.data);
          sessionStorage.setItem('accessJWT', res.data.accessJWT);
          localStorage.setItem('sms', JSON.stringify(res.data.refreshJWT));
        }
       console.log(res.data);
      })
     .catch((err) => {
       reject(err);
     });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    reject(error);
  }
 });
};
```

> index.js (root API)

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const ENDPOINTS = {
  LOGIN: 'user/login',
  LOGOUT: 'user/logout',
  REGISTER: 'user/register',
};

const baseURL = 'http://localhost:3040/v2/';
export const createEndpointsAPI = (endpoint) => {
  let url = baseURL + endpoint + '/';
  return {
   fetchAll: () => axios.get(url),
   fetchById: (id) => axios.get(url + id),
   create: (newData) => axios.post(url, newData),
   update: (updateData, id) => axios.put(url + id, updateData),
   delete: (id) => axios.delete(url + id),
 };
};
```

[image: isAuth return false when login is correct but it shown isAuth = true in redux state]

[image: isAuth return false and then return true after second click on login]

[image: isAuth shown true in redux state while return false in console.log(isAuth)]

> App.js

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <CssBaseline />
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact>
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <PrivateRoute path='/dashboard'>
        <Dashboard />
      </PrivateRoute>
      <Route path='*' component={() => '404 NOT FOUND'} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

> PrivateRoute.js

```
 import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

 const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
 const { isAuth } = useSelector((state) => state.login);
 console.log(isAuth);
 return (
  <Route
   {...rest}
   render={(props) => {
     isAuth ? (
       <Component {...props} />
     ) : (
       <Redirect
         to={{
           pathname: '/',
           state: { from: props.location },
         }}
       />
      );
      }}
     />
    );
   };

  export default PrivateRoute;
```

The problem is, isAuth is a redux state, it should return true when the user login correctly, but it's not, I console.log(isAuth) and it prints false for the first time even user login correctly, and if I click login one more time it prints true in the console log and redirects the user to the dashboard page. **I don't know why isAuth is returned false for the first time when use is login correctly?** Please help check the above code from top to bottom, I provide you everythings.

Comment: I `console.log('Log In)` in `NewUserLogin` function, it actually return isAuth is false then Logged in, so what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log: `console.log(isAuth);` logs a [stale closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/), you could try an effect on isAuth and redirect when it's true.

Here is an example:

```
const Component = (propps) => {
  const { isLoading, isAuth, error, message } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.login
  );
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    //...dispatches but doesn't check isAuth
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    //go to dashboard if isAuth is true
    if (isAuth) history.push('/dashboard');
  }, [isAuth]);//run effect when isAuth changes
};
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to avoid stale closure? How do you render effect on isAuth?

Comment: @Jonh Added example

Comment: I apply your idea by using `useEffect` and add dependency `[isAuth]`, it's working but it showed a warning in virtual studio code inside `useEffect(()=>{},[isAuth])` `React Hook has a missing dependency: 'history'`

Comment: In `PrivateRoute.js` I also use `isAuth` from `redux state`, and it returns `false`, do I need to use `useEffect` in `PrivateRoute.js` as well.

Comment: I didn't know what is the exact issued with my `PrivateRoute.js`, even if I clear `Token` from `localStorage & session`, I still can access `localhost:3001/dashboard`, there is no `restriction` at all